# In the rest api, how to return records that match any condition?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am developing a single page aplication that need to access some resources in Magento.

In this application, I need to return all customers that match any of the search fields the user filled. 
Example: Get every user that the group_id id 1 or the website_id is 3.

Is there any way to do this in the rest or soap api or do I need to implement a custom api endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

From [our docs for Request Example SOAP V2 (Complex Filter)](https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.list.html):

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

// If some stuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'group_id',
            'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => '1,3')
        )
    )
);
$result = $client->customerCustomerList($session, $complexFilter);

var_dump ($result);
```

Comment: But I need to search in two different attributes. In the example, it will search for users in the group 1 or 3. What I need is to search for users in the group 1 or with the website_id 3

Comment: The example from our docs should suffice, no? Just change the `group_id` search value to 1, and add a second member to the `complex_filter` with `website_id` of 3.

Comment: I tried it using a ruby soap client but it only returns records that match both conditions. Tried using rest too, but got the same result as the soap api.